# Firebase firestore update value of maps items

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, firebase-storage

I have a document of the following format on Firebase Firestore(in android):

```
map1: {
        email1: true;
        email2: false;
}
```

I want to change email2 value to true.
Email is in the format `xy.z@xyz.com`

The following task is not updated using `update()` method, as the first argument includes dot notation and email also contains dots.

Comment: Please add a screenshot of your database structure.